# Buscar lineas en archivo en intervalo de tiempo con bash

Tags: date, bash, terminal, txt, busqueda

Tengo un archivo **txt** en el cual esta enlistada todos los archivos del directorio. En el cual tiene el sigiente formato: **los pirmeros 2 digitos son el dia - los siguientes 4 son la hora (24hrs) hora y minuto - los ultimos dos son los segundos, las letras se lo agrega el programa, los ultimos 6 digitos, los primeros 4 son el año y los otos dos son el mes.**

```
03-2233-23L-A199609
03-2245-31L-A199609
03-2312-42L-A199609
04-0213-21L-A199609
04-0241-11L-A199609
04-1412-41L-A199609
05-0547-12L-A199609
05-1232-34L-A199609
05-2001-09L-A199609
```

lo que quiero realizar es que el usuario ingrese un intervalo de tiempo, con **Fecha: año mes dia** , **Hora: hr min seg**, iniciales y finales del intervalo de tiempo, con el realice una busqueda en el **txt** los archivos que se encuentren en el intervalo de tiempo los lea y guardarlos en un nuevo **txt**. Este es el codigo que tengo, pero no se como realizar la busqueda con los datos de los datos con el intervalo de tiempo.

```
#!/bin/bash/

#Pedir valores de inicio y final de busqueda de archivos

#Valores de inicio

echo "Introduccion de datos
      Fecha: Año Mes Dia (xxxx yy zz)
      Hora(24hrs):Hr Min Seg (aa bb cc)"

echo 'Valores iniciales' 
read -p "Fecha: " year mes dia 
read -p " Hora: " hr min seg 
echo

#Valores Finales

echo 'Valores Finales'
read -p "Fecha: " yearf mesf diaf
read -p " Hora: " hrf minf segf
echo
echo 'Iniciales: '$year $mes $dia $hr:$min:$seg
echo '  Finales: '$yearf $mesf $diaf $hrf:$minf:$segf

archivo=list.txt

while leer= read -r line
do 
    dat=$(echo "$line")

 if [ -e $dat ]
    then 
        echo 'El archivo exite ' $dat
        #Guardar dato en archivo
    else
        echo 'El archivo no exite ' $dat

 fi;
done < $archivo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash/

#Pedir valores de inicio y final de busqueda de archivos

#Valores de inicio

echo "Introduccion de datos
      Fecha: Año Mes Dia (xxxx yy zz)
      Hora(24hrs):Hr Min Seg (aa bb cc)"

echo 'Valores iniciales' 
read -p "Fecha: " year mes dia 
read -p " Hora: " hr min seg 
echo

#Valores Finales

echo 'Valores Finales'
read -p "Fecha: " yearf mesf diaf
read -p " Hora: " hrf minf segf
echo
echo 'Iniciales: '$year $mes $dia $hr:$min:$seg
echo '  Finales: '$yearf $mesf $diaf $hrf:$minf:$segf

archivo=list.txt

while leer= read -r line
do 
    dat=$(echo "$line")

 if [ -e $dat ]
    then 
        echo 'El archivo exite ' $dat
        #Guardar dato en archivo
    else
        echo 'El archivo no exite ' $dat

 fi;
done < $archivo
```